# AnimatedVectorDrawable Support <21

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

in project i use:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
```

in my activity i use:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

and i have `AnimatedVectorDrawable`

> vector_test_anim.xml

```
<animated-vector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:drawable="@drawable/circle_black_simple"
  tools:ignore="NewApi">
  <target
      android:animation="@animator/blink"
      android:name="bl"/>

  </animated-vector>
```

> circle_black_simple.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="500.0"
android:viewportWidth="500.0"
android:width="24dp">
 <group
        android:name="blinkGroup">
        <path
            android:name="bl"
            android:fillColor="#696969"
            android:pathData="M250,250m-210,0a210,210 0,1 1,420 0a210,210 0,1 1,-420 0" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

i trying set my vector animation in XML, and i have ResourceException
i trying set my vector animation in my adapter and i check `isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled`

```
 if(AppCompatDelegate.isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG,"isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled");
            mBinding.sendStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_test_anim);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"NOT isCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled");
        }
```

I have not obtained paste `AnimatedVectorDrawable` in view.

Please help me, support library I can not use a version lower?

Comment: so not working  AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVectorDrawableCompat
                        = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, R.drawable.vector_test_anim)

Comment: did you include `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary i use support library 24.2 , this line i am deleting from gradle file

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still need that line in your `build.gradle`, did that change in 24.2.0??

Comment: @LewisMcGeary i reading this post “AppCompat — Age of the vectors” https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88 it says , that this line need delete

Comment: You might be misreading the article, that line should be included!

Comment: @LewisMcGeary i try, but i trying this option and so not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124427/discussion-between-lewis-mcgeary-and--).